# How to Open SQL Server Management Studio 2016

Tags: sql-server

I have just Install SQL server 2016 and it has been installed successfully. Now I am looking for the Sql Server Management Studio to login into the Database Engine. but not able to see there. Also not able to open it by executing

```
ssms.exe
```

Path:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\
```

When i re-run the setup to install management studio it looks that we need to download it from [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt238290.aspx): Why its missing with SQL server .ISO File. ?

Please advise if there any other option available or I can found it in DVD without downloading it again.

Comment: At least in previous versions, and likely also in 2016, Management Studio is a separate component that you can select during installation. (For example, it isn't entirely uncommon to not want to install it on dedicated database servers.) Did you accidentally select not to install it?

Comment: I select all the packages but not able to see it there.

Comment: You will have to download the package separately

Answer (score 1):

Starting with SQL Server 2016, Management Studio is a separate, stand-alone product and it does not come with SQL Server.  You need to download and install it separately.
See [here](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/2018/01/sql-server-management-studio-ssms.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

On SQL2016 iso, during installation there is no option to choose install sql management studio. However, it has link to download 'Install SQL Server Management Tools'. What Windows os are you running?. In my case, I install windows 2016 and need to install vcredist_x64.exe before install sql2016. After succeed install sql2016 and sql management studio, as you mentioned, I have to launch it from dos command line 'ssms'.